# How should I connect a new dimmer switch?

Tags: wiring, switch

I'm trying to install a [dimmer switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HJSJ6VG). Are the 2 black wires acting as a pass through? Obviously, green to green, but then what? both blacks and brown, leave white capped? Please help, sorry for being a newb. :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your reason for getting that specific dimmer in particular?

Comment: alexa compatible, rather than having 30+ lifx bulbs, thought maybe dimmers/switches would be better. Can also be flashed with tasmota for home assistant.

Comment: ...why are you shopping for this sort of thing on Amazon? (you'll notice that what you have doesn't have a UL/ETL/CSA/... *listing* or *labeling* that'd indicate that it passed mains-safety testing)

Comment: Voting to close. OP indicated abandonment.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to identify the hot and the switched hot. It looked like the hot goes to black and the switched hot goes to the brown. Connect white to whites and ground to ground as you thought.

Comment: and sorry, whats the diff between hot and switched hot? how do I identify?

Comment: Hot is the feed from the main with the switch turned off one side will have voltage the other will not with the switch on both sides are hot  therefore hot and switched hot.

Comment: i think im done here, trying to use a multimeter to find the hot, got an arc and scared the piss out of myself.